# Question regarding configuration of Next JS on Cloud Run with Docker Images

Tags: docker, github, next.js, action, next-auth

I have a question regarding an approach and how secure it is. Basically I have a next js app which I push to Cloud Run via Github Actions. Now in Github Actions I have defined secrets which I then pass via github action yml file to Docker. Then in Docker I pass them to environment variables at build time. But then I use next.config.js to make it available to the app at build time. Here are my files

Github Action Yml File

```html
name: nextjs-cloud-run

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  GCP_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
  GCP_REGION: europe-west1
  # project-name but it can be anything you want
  REPO_NAME: some-repo-name

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # This step is where our service account will be authenticated
      - uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0.2.0
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEYBASE64 }}
          service_account_email: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_EMAIL }}
      - name: Enable the necessary APIs and enable docker auth
        run: |-
          gcloud services enable containerregistry.googleapis.com
          gcloud services enable run.googleapis.com
          gcloud --quiet auth configure-docker
      - name: Build, tag image & push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          push: true
          tags: "gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/collect-opinion-frontend:${{ github.sha }}"
          secrets: |
            "NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL }}"
            "NEXTAUTH_SECRET=${{ secrets.NEXTAUTH_SECRET }}"
            "NEXTAUTH_URL=${{ secrets.NEXTAUTH_URL }}"
      - name: Deploy Image
        run: |-
          gcloud components install beta --quiet
          gcloud beta run deploy $REPO_NAME --image gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA \
            --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID \
            --platform managed \
            --region $GCP_REGION \
            --allow-unauthenticated \
            --quiet
```

This is my Dockerfile for Next Js

```js
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
    else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
    fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

# get the environment vars from secrets
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL \
    --mount=type=secret,id=NEXTAUTH_SECRET \
    --mount=type=secret,id=NEXTAUTH_URL \
    export NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL=$(cat /run/secrets/NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL) && \
    export NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/NEXTAUTH_SECRET) && \
    export NEXTAUTH_URL=$(cat /run/secrets/NEXTAUTH_URL) && \
    yarn build

# RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

My next.config.js file

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ... rest of the configuration.
  output: "standalone",
  env: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    NEXTAUTH_SECRET: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    NEXTAUTH_URL: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL, // Pass through env variables
  },
};
```

My question is that, does this create a security issue with the fact that the environment variable could somehow be accessed via the client?

According to Next JS Documentation that should not be the case or at least that's how I understand. Snippet from the site

```html
Note: environment variables specified in this way will always be included in the JavaScript bundle, prefixing the environment variable name with NEXT_PUBLIC_ only has an effect when specifying them through the environment or .env files.
```

I would appreciate if you could advise me on this

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I've added the env in `next.config file`, `github->actions-secrets` (calling the secrets in the workflow.yml) and `cloud run`, but none of this seems to work. Have you solved it?

Comment: Hey @AlitonOliveira, unfortunately I had to simply push .env.production to git repo, since I did not find a solution either :(